# Linq query on XML to Select multiple elements of subnodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to select all distinct values of child from following xml

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child>value 1</child>
    <child>value 2</child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child>value 1</child>
    <child>value 4</child>
  </parent>
</root>
```

I tried following:

```
var vals  = (from res in XmlResources.Elements("root").Elements("parent") select res)
                                        .SelectMany(r => r.Elements("child")).Distinct().ToList();
```

But can't get the value from it, gives me value wrapped in tag and not Distinct

Is it possible to show both ways to get it - query and chaining aka lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is possible both ways

```
var doc = new XDocument("your xml string");
var values = (from c in doc.Root.Descendants("child") select c.Value).Distinct();
```

//chaining style

```
var values = doc.Root.Descendants("child").Select(c=>c.Value).Distinct();
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! didn't realise I can go straight to child, was trying to chain to it through Elements("root").Elements("parent")

Comment: Why are you using a statement body lambda when just `.Select(c => c.Value)` would be simpler? Also please note it's `Select`, not `select`.

Comment: (I've edited the `select` to `Select`, and also fixed up the name of `Descendants` and the string literals... I assumed you wouldn't mind. I've left the lambda expression in the awkward syntax for the moment, in case you really wanted it that way.)

Answer (score 3):

You're selecting the elements, and the *elements* are all distinct. You need to get the distinct *values*. For example:

```
var values = XmlResources.Element("root")
                         .Elements("parent")
                         .Elements("child")
                         .Select(x => x.Value)
                         .Distinct();
```

There's really no benefit in using a query expression here - it only adds cruft. I only use a query expression when the query has multiple aspects to it (e.g. a where *and* a meaningful select, or a join). For *just a select* or *just a where* it's pretty pointless. So yes, you can use:

```
var values = (from x in XmlResources.Element("root")
                                    .Elements("parent")
                                    .Elements("child")
              select x.Value).Distinct();
```

... but why would you? It's a lot less clear IMO.

Note that if you don't care too much about the root/parent/child hierarchy, and are happy to just get *all* the `child` descendants, you can use:

```
var values = XmlResources.Descendants("child")
                         .Select(x => x.Value)
                         .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks, will take that into account, just want to learn doing things query way.

Comment: @SergejPopov: Learn to do things the appropriate way for the context - don't force yourself to use a query expression when it doesn't help you. That's like forcing yourself to use reflection when you can invoke something directly...